# Jqgrid: navigation based on the selected row

Tags: jqgrid

I was trying to enable navigation based on a selected row. So, the user select a row from jQgrid, and when press the show (is there a show button for the grid, I saw edit, add etc), it needs to go to a new page based on the url (part of the row).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function getLink() {
//      var rowid = $("#customer_list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
        var rowid = $("#customer_list").getGridParam('selrow');
        var MyCellData = $("#customer_list").jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'dataUrl');
        return MyCellData;
    }

    $("#customer_list").jqGrid({
        url:'mytestList',
        editurl:'jq_edit_test',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames:['Call Id','Title','dataUrl'],
        colModel:[
          {name:'callId', width:80, search:false},
          {name:'title', width:200, sortable:false},
          {name:'dataUrl',hidden:true}
        ],
        rowNum:10,
        sortname:'lastUpdated',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        pager:'#customer_list_pager',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true
    }).navGrid('#customer_list_pager',
      {add:true,edit:true,del:false,search:true,refresh:true}, 
      {closeAfterEdit:true, afterSubmit:afterSubmitEvent}, // edit options
      {addCaption:'Create New something', afterSubmit:afterSubmitEvent,
       savekey:[true,13]}, // add options
      {afterSubmit:afterSubmitEvent}  // delete options
    );
    $("#customer_list").jqGrid('filterToolbar');
});
```

so, the url is passed for each row as dataUrl. I'm trying to read it and set to the button. When debug through firebug, the rowid was 223 (there were only 12 rows in the grid), and the cell value is empty. Currently the button is kept outside the grid, but it may better to be it part of the vavGrid

thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The code like following could solve your problem

```
$("#customer_list").jqGrid ('navButtonAdd', '#customer_list_pager',
    { caption: ""/*"Show"*/, buttonicon: "ui-icon-extlink", title: "Show Link",
      onClickButton: function() {
          var grid = $("#customer_list");
          var rowid = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
          window.location = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'dataUrl');
      }
    });
```

Comment: worked great.. thanks for showing how to set the jqueryui icon .. i had an issue with JSON data, that was why the url didn't read correct initially.. thanks again

Answer (score 4):

You could just make the show button be part of each row in the grid and use a [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) to turn it into a URL.

Based on the example in the wiki, you'll probably need something along the lines of

```
function myformatter ( cellvalue, options, rowObject )
{
    return "<a href=\"" + cellvalue + "\">Show</a>";
}
```

Comment: I tried a similar approach, by making one of the cell a link (formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: getLink() ).. I could turn the url column into a link as you suggested, but may waste some space. Still not sure what is wrong with getCell method !!

Comment: @bsreekanth: I guess it depends on how wide your table is.  A *Show* column would only add 50px or so to the width.  However it would allow people to open the links in a new window instead of in the current one (not sure how important that functionality is to you though).  Otherwise Oleg's solution looks like it'd work.