# Is there a way to add a column with buttons in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have some data that I'd like to display in jqqgrid.  In addition to add, edit, and delete, there are other actions that can be taken on a selected record.  I like the flow of having a button/link for that action in that record's row.  Is there a way to add a column & buttons/links within jqgrid which isn't bound to data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [Jqgrid: navigation based on the selected row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024075/jqgrid-navigation-based-on-the-selected-row/3024278#3024278). Probably you should create a custom button in the Navigator (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons) in the same way.

If it is not what you are searching for, please decribe a little more detailed or on an example what you exactly want to have.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, please go to the [jqGrid Demo Page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) and open the **Row Editing** | **Custom Edit** demo for an example.