# jqGrid how to override the "view" m

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid where the "View" icon is enabled (view:true), so that a user picks a row in the grid, and then clicks the icon in the navbar to view the row.

Thing is, what I really want to have happen is a redirect to a different URL, with the rowid included as a parameter in the URL (e.g. foo.htm?rowid=5)

I went over the docs, and searched stackoverflow, but didn't see an obvious answer jump up. I'm sure there is an easy answer to this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at my previous answer [Jqgrid: navigation based on the selected row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024075/jqgrid-navigation-based-on-the-selected-row/3024278#3024278).

It seems you just should add a new [custom button](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons) which looks like a "View" button and do something based on the selected row. Try this one http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ViewRedirect.htm which redirect to your the question if you click on the "View" button from the navigator.