# jqgrid editGridRow selection list for each cell

Tags: select, dynamic, jqgrid, modal-dialog

In my case, I want the user to pickup the values by clicking on a ">" type image at the end of the cell and a modal window is opened. Within the modal window a dynamic way to pass the value selected back to the cell.

Comment: Explain your requirements clearly, please

Comment: Within the modal window a dynamic way to pass the value selected back to the cell. this line is not clear

Comment: It seems he wants the user to be able to click on a `>`  image link, open a dialog, pick a value, and then dynamically pass that value back to the table cell.

Comment: Yes. Justin is correct. That is what I am looking for.

Comment: okay but dont post your question again and again please. I'm going to look for a solution for you.

Comment: i m sorry. when i found my question was not answered. i thought i should reframe my question because i did not think users would be reading comments on this post. i will delete the other question..

Answer (score 0):

You should look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810579/jqgrid-custom-edit-dialog)..instead of having custom button you can have an image button with each cell, in this answer he's adding a custom button in pager, but you can have a custom button with each cell like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743983/adding-a-custom-button-in-row-in-jqgrid/11744722#11744722).

Now after adding a image button, on click function you can get the value of the column using getCol and open a dialog using jQuery like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587480/jquery-modal-dialog-and-jqgrid) and then you can use setCol property of jqGrid to set the value of column.

Now try to write code using this approach. If you get any difficulty let us know.