# JQGrid - How can I Create Check box in Navigation to Trigger Multiselect or SingleSelect

Tags: jqgrid

```
function bind_single_select() {
  if (!$("input#single").length > 0) {
    $("span.single_select").prepend("<input type='checkbox' name='single' id='single' checked='checked' style='vertical-align:middle' />");
  }
  $("table#gridTable").find("tr").click(function () {
    if ($("input#single").attr("checked")) {
      $(".trSelected").removeClass("trSelected");
      $(this).addClass("trSelected");
    }
  });
}
```

I found this in Flexigrid but in JQGrid How can I do it.

Another Question :

```
.navButtonAdd('#pager',
              { caption: "Add",
                buttonimg: "/Areas/Pages/Content/Images/add.png",
                onClickButton: function () {
                    PopupCenter('<%= Url.Action("CreatePublisher","Publisher") %>',
                                'CreatePublisher', '500', '300');
                }, position: "last"
              })
```

the buttonimg is not work even I use 
ui-icon-plus

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The second part of your question is very easy to answer. The parameter `buttonimg` is no more supported in the `navButtonAdd` function. You should use [buttonicon](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons) instead. An example you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024075/jqgrid-navigation-based-on-the-selected-row/3024278#3024278). In general as a value of [buttonicon](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons) you can use any from the [jQuery UI Framework Icons](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#icons).

To toggle `multipleSearch` parameter you can just define search parameters of `navGrid` separately and toggle the value of the `multipleSearch` property. To make all more easy I suggest to use an additional parameter `recreateFilter:true`.

```
var grid = jQuery('#list');
var pSearch = { multipleSearch:false, recreateFilter:true };
grid.jqGrid({
    // all jqGrid parameters
}).jqGrid ('navGrid', '#pager', {edit:false, add:false, del:false, refresh:true, view:false},
           {},{},{},pSearch));

$("#pager_left table.navtable tbody tr").append ( // here 'pager' part or #pager_left is the id of the pager
    '<td><div><input type="checkbox" class="myMultiSearch" id="navMultiSearch"/>Multi-Search</div></td>');
$(".myMultiSearch").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        pSearch.multipleSearch = true;
        $(".myMultiSearch").attr("checked","checked");
    }
    else {
        pSearch.multipleSearch = false;
        $(".myMultiSearch").removeAttr("checked");
    }
});
```

On the small [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MultisearchSwitching.htm) I inserted both internal and external checkboxes to the navigation bar and a custom button additionally:

[image]

Comment: How to replace checkbox and its caption with two-state pushpin button which shows chekced and unchecked states in single button without text?