# jqgrid add custom button to nav layer to go to new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

OK, I am using jqgrid to only display a subset of information.

I want to use a custom button in the nav layer to navigate to a new page where the user can enter a new record.

i.e. I want a button that says (New record" which, when clicked loads a new pagewhich contains my record input form and code.

I can create the bvutton fine, but I can't seem to find the right way to get it to call a function which loads a new page.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use such a code to add a button to the nav layer:

Html:

```
<table id='mygrid'> ... </table> <!-- grid -->
<div id='mygrid-panel' class='scroll'></div> <!-- nav layer -->
```

JS:

```
$("#mygrid").navButtonAdd('#mygrid-panel', {
  caption: "New record",
  title: "Click here to add new record",
  buttonicon: "ui-icon-plusthick",
  onClickButton: function() {
     // perform something...
  },
  position: "first"
});
```

Hope I understand you correctly what you want.

Comment: Fabulous, worked perfectly! The mistake I was making was to put a call to a function in the parameter, not a function itself... Doh!!

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024075/jqgrid-navigation-based-on-the-selected-row/3024278#3024278). Probably it is what you need?