# jqGrid navButtonAdd onClick function with post parameter

Tags: jqgrid

I have create custom button Details which needs to redirect me on page depends of selected row.

```
.navButtonAdd('#resourcePager',

                        {
                            caption: "Details",
                            buttonicon: "ui-icon-document",
                            onClickButton: function (id) {
                                alert("/ResourceManager/Details/" + id);
                            },
                            position: "first"
                        }
        )
```

But I can not see "id" parameter in alert.
Does anyone have an idea how I can post parameter from grid on navButtonAdd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024075/jqgrid-navigation-based-on-the-selected-row/3024278#3024278). It seems to me that it will answer on your question. You should of course modify the code depend on how you want to make "redirecting" to the page which you need.

Comment: Thank you Oleg.
This is expected solution