# jqGrid navGrid button calling ASP.NET MVC view - how?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am using: VS 2010, ASP.NET MVC2, jqGrid 3.8.2.

I want to have the navGrid 'Edit' button open a different view in the controller.  I have tried a number of things to no avail.  In order to open the selected row, I assume I will need to append the id to the url.

```
jQuery('#listComponents').jqGrid({
    url: '/Components/Get',
    editurl: '/Components/Edit',
    ...
    }).navGrid('#pagerComponents', {edit:true, ...}, {url: '/Components/Edit'});
```

Any suggestions are welcome.  If I can't get it to work, I will add an 'Edit' button outside the jqGrid and do a normal Html.ActionLink call to open the different view.

Thanks!

**Update**

Following @Oleg's answer, I now have the following working perfectly:

```
    jQuery('#listComponents').jqGrid(
    {
        url: '/Components/Get/',
        ...
    }).navGrid('#pagerComponents', { edit: false, ...})
    .navButtonAdd('#pagerComponents', {
        caption: "",
        title: "Edit Component",
        buttonicon: "ui-icon-pencil",
        onClickButton: function () {
            var id = jQuery("#listComponents").getGridParam('selrow');
            if (id) {
                var data = jQuery("#listComponents").getRowData(id);
                window.location = '/Components/Edit/' + data.COMPONENTID;
            }
            else {
                alert("Please select a row to edit.");
            }
        }});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option `{edit:true, ...}` of the [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#how_to_use) follow to the usage of [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow) method of the form editing, so the dialog will be displayed and not the View of your MVC controller. To have the behavior which you want you should use `{edit:false, ...}` setting and add [custom button](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons) which look exactly like the original "Edit" button. To make this you should use `buttonicon: "ui-icon-pencil"` parameter (see `editicon` default parameter in the `navGrid` [source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.formedit.js#L1574)). In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024075/jqgrid-navigation-based-on-the-selected-row/3024278#3024278) you will find code example. You can additionally use `$.jgrid.nav.edittitle` as the title parameter:

```
var grid = $("#listComponents");
grid.jqGrid({
    url: '/Components/Get',
    editurl: '/Components/Edit',
    ...
});
grid.navGrid('#pagerComponents', {edit:false, ...}, ...);
grid.jqGrid ('navButtonAdd', '#pagerComponents',
    { caption: "", buttonicon: "ui-icon-pencil", title: $.jgrid.nav.edittitle,
      onClickButton: function() {
          var rowid = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
          window.location = '/Components/Edit/' + 'rowid';
      }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me an answer to a problem that I couldn't solve.  This saved me a lot of time.  Worked perfectly.