# Redefine jgrid navgrid add/edit button

Tags: jqgrid

Is there any way, in jqgrid, to redefine the function to call when the "add" button of the navgrid?

The only thing I've found is to [add a new button redefining "onclickbutton" property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286562/jqgrid-navgrid-button-calling-asp-net-mvc-view-how) , and I've  looked [at code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.formedit.js#L1788), but I think that is impossible, isn't it?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code which you referenced you can find [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.formedit.js#L1779-1783) of code. So is you defines `addfunc` [option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#parameters) of `navGrid` you can implement your own implementation of "Add" button.

Alternatively you can just use `add: false` option of `navGrid` and then uses [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_buttons) to add your custom button which looks exactly like "Add" button.

Comment: Thanks, I had implemented the second option, but now I'll try the first one and I'll say something.

Comment: @Marc: You are welcome! It's important to place `addfunc` option in the correct place as `navGrid`: it should be in the same object where `edit: true` are defined: see `parameters` part of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition) options (really `parameters` part and not `prmAdd` part of the options).