# Grabbing selected row's ID to bring up a fancybox widget with custom button in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am trying to bring up a fancybox widget using a custom button in jqgrid. To do this, I would need to grab the Id of the selected row. I am currently trying this to do it. And it is not working. The custom button shows, it responds to the click event, but I cannot get the selected id. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!!!

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pagernav',
            {edit:true,add:false,del:false,search:false}, 
           { 
                height:280,
                reloadAfterSubmit:true,
                closeAfterEdit:true,
                editCaption: "Edit Sample",
                bSubmit: "Submit",
                bCancel: "Cancel",
                bClose: "Close",
                checkOnSubmit:true,
                saveData: "Data has been changed! Save changes?",
                bYes : "Yes",
                bNo : "No",
                bExit : "Cancel"
              }
            ).jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#pagernav',{
                   caption:"Add", 
                   buttonicon:"ui-icon-add", 
                   onClickButton: function(lastsel){ 
                     alert("Adding Row to id" + lastsel);
                   }, 
                   position:"last"
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Look [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024075/jqgrid-navigation-based-on-the-selected-row/3024278#3024278). It shows how to get `'selrow'` parameter of jqGrid which you need. In case of multiselect scenario (`multiselect: true`) you should use `'selarrrow'` parameter instead.

The only parameter of navButtonAdd is the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) from the `click` event (see [jqGrid code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/grid.formedit.js#L1927)). Because the click is on *your custom button* it bring you very little information. You can use the event only for example to implement different actions if the button was clicked in combination with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> or some other keys pressed. In all standard scenarios you have to use `'selrow'` or `'selarrrow'` parameters.

You should be careful, because the custom button can be clicked even if no rows are selected. In the case the value of `'selrow'` parameter is `null`  (the value of `'selarrrow'` is empty array `[]`).

You can consider to implement hide/show or enable/disable some navigator buttons based on whether or which row is selected. See [this](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/HideShowNavGridButtonsDynamically.htm) and [this](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EdableDisableEditDelNavigatorButtons.htm) demos from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056859/jqgrid-resolve-the-grid-pager-id-dynamically/7057838#7057838) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373693/jqgrid-how-to-set-toolbar-options-based-on-column-value-in-row-selected/5376355#5376355) old answers.